Confusion about time dilation
Suppose a clock that ticks every second is moving at half the speed of light away from me.
Without special relativity, I would see the ticks at every 1.5 seconds, since the light from the next tick has to travel 0.5 light-seconds further than the light from the current tick.
Using the Lorentz factor, the time between ticks would appear $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (\frac{1}{2})^2}} \approx 1.155$ times longer to me. Now, if I want to include the time it takes for the light to travel to me, I could either calculate it as

The clock ticks (in its reference frame) every second, so it travels 0.5 light seconds between ticks, making each tick 0.5 seconds longer for a total of 1.155 + 0.5 = 1.655 seconds between ticks.
The clock ticks (in my reference frame) every 1.155 seconds, so it travels 0.578 light seconds between ticks, making each tick 0.578 seconds longer for a total of 1.155 + 0.578 = 1.733 seconds between ticks.

Which of these is the correct calculation?

In general, it's easier to think of Special Relativity questions like this if the clock is traveling in a circle around you, and you are sitting on a rotating stool.  So the clock is never traveling away from you or towards you.  Then you don't have to add in that extra redshift calculations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Relativistic_longitudinal_Doppler_effect Does this answer your question? (Think of the clock as a light source with a frequency of 1 Hz in the reference frame of the source)

@foolishmuse special relativity does not apply to accelerated frames.

@JimmyJames any item traveling through space, regardless of being in a straight line or traveling in a circle, will still face exactly the same kinetic time dilation of special relativity.

@foolishmuse Ttravelling in a circle at a constant speed requires accelerating towards the center of the circle.  While, it's possible that you can ignore that the idea that this is obvious and can be treated just like linear motion is an easy place to start seems very questionable.  If you can provide a reference for this, that would be a different situation.

@JimmyJames https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434539/time-dilation-for-circular-movement

@foolishmuse While it is correct that this scenario is a valid case for SR (good call), Looking at this answer, I still am not convinced this is a great example for getting started.

Calculation 2 is correct. That is how you determine the tick frequency working entirely in your reference frame.
The same calculation can be done in the reference frame of the clock, but you must perform the change of coordinates correctly. In that reference frame, you are moving away from the clock at 0.5c; that is, every second, you move 0.5 light-seconds further away from the clock. When one tick has reached you, the next tick is 1 light-second behind. It takes 2 seconds to catch up with you (because you have moved an additional 1 light-second in that time). Thus the ticks reach you every 2 seconds in the clock's reference frame. However, your clock is slowed down because you are moving, so according to your clock, the ticks reach you every 2/1.1547 = 1.732 seconds.
Of course, you get the same answer in both reference frames, as you must.

(+1) I think I almost understand time dilation, but could you confirm just to be sure please? Time dilation simply means: if my friend boards a rocket and goes revolving around the nearest black hole and returns, then his clock will have ticked less than my clock on earth... Anything beyond this plain experimental fact is basically excuse-finding/theorizing/attempts-at-justification, correct?

... on a similar note, length contraction is even more abstract since there is no direct experiment that can demonstrate length contraction, as separating two objects and then bringing them back later to the same locality always reverts the lengths to be the same as originally, right?

@James Well, there are a number of different experiments you can do to demonstrate time dilation. You don't need a black hole. It has even been checked in Earth's gravity well and using speeds no higher than those of ordinary airplanes. So I think your statement is too strong. But if your point is that many different "theories" of time dilation can explain the same experimental facts, that is true. In this example, the two observers (using their own reference frames) have different "theories" of whose time is dilated, but they still agree on the experimental results.

@ anon thank you. I am starting to favor the principle that "if it's in different place and at different time, no need to theorize or peep at what the neighbor is seeing/doing", i.e. to compare any two things, bring them to the same locality at the same time and do the measurement directly. Is this too strong a stance for analyzing special relativity effects, do you think?

@James Yes, I mostly agree. In general, if you have two events (position/time pairs), observers can disagree on both the temporal and spatial distances between them. And that disagreement is OK. Relativity gives you a framework for understanding why those disagreements are "safe" in that you will both make the same predictions. It's unnecessary to worry about what your neighbor believes, because the framework works. But analyzing both worldviews is useful for people who are first learning relativity, because it helps them understand why the disagreements are safe.

@ anon thank you, the discussion has bettered my understanding of SR.



The clock ticks (in its reference frame) every second, so it
travels $0.5$ light seconds between ticks, making each tick $0.5$ seconds
longer for a total of $1.155 + 0.5 = 1.655$ seconds between ticks.


This first method is incorrect because you are using the time of the moving clock ($1 \ \text{second}$) as measured in its own rest frame to measure the time interval used to calculate the distance in the frame that sees the clock moving. The distance is measured in the reference frame of the observer that is receiving the signal, so we must use the time interval between emitted signals as measured by the receiving observer. If observer $\text{A}$ is observing signals from clock $\text{B}$, that is moving away from him, the distance clock $\text{A}$ moves in $\text{A}$'s reference frame must be calculated using the interval measured on $\text{A}$'s clock ($1.155 \ \text{seconds}$).
The second method is the correct one and is in agreement with the result given by the relativistic Doppler effect.
$${f_r} = {f_s}\sqrt{\frac{1-v/c}{1+v/c}} = \sqrt{\frac{0.5}{1.5}} \approx 0.577,$$
where $v$ is the velocity of the clock going away from the observer, $f_r$ is the frequency of the signal received by the observer, and $f_s$ is the frequency of the signal emitted by the clock that is going away. Since $f_r$ is a frequency, we need the inverse to find the time interval between received signals, which is $\Delta T_r = 1/f_r \approx 1.732 \ \text{seconds}$, if the source clock that is going away emits signals at the frequency of once per second.

The right answer is 2), as already pointed out.
The mistake in 1) is that you forgot to time-dilate the $0.5 \ \text{s}$.
$$\text{Total period in your reference frame} = 1 \ \text{s} \times \gamma + 0.5 \ \text{s} \times \gamma = 1.5 \times 1.155 \ \text{s} = 1.732 \ \text{s}.$$
